# Custom listview has false information Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, baseadapter

I'm new coding Xamarin, so i made a custom adapter, my idea was to save everything, when the user closes the app. After some research I thought this code was gonna work:

```
List<GardenClass> MyList = new List<GardenClass> ();

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        listview.Adapter = new GardenAdapter(this, MyList);
    }

protected override void OnPause()
    {
        base.OnPause();
        write();
    }

public void write()
    {
        string path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.Personal);
        string filename = Path.Combine(path, "Files.txt");

        try
        {
           File.WriteAllText(filename,JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyList));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to serialize. Reason: " + e.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }



public class GardenAdapter : BaseAdapter<GardenClass>
{
    private Context MyCon;

    List<GardenClass> items;
    Activity context;

    public GardenAdapter(Activity context, List<GardenClass> items)
        : base()
    {
        MyCon = context;
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }
    public override GardenClass this[int position]
    {
        get { return items[position]; }
    }
    public override int Count
    {
        get { return items.Count; }
    }



    public override Android.Views.View GetView(int position, Android.Views.View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var item = items[position];

        Android.Views.View view;
        if (convertView == null) { 
        view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ListItem, null);
        } else { view = convertView; }
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1).Text = item.ToDo;
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView2).Text = "Week " + item.Week.ToString();
        view.FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.checkBox1).Checked = item.Done;

        CheckBox MyCheckBox;
        checkding = view.FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.checkBox1);


        // The folowing code prevents the checkbox of stealing the focus, which make a singular listview item unclickable
        MyCheckBox.Focusable = false;
        MyCheckBox.FocusableInTouchMode = false;
        MyCheckBox.Clickable = true;

        return view;

    }
}

[Serializable]
public class ZaaiSpul
{
    public int Week { get; set; }
    public string ToDo { get; set; }
    public bool Done { get; set; }
}
```

But when the `OnPause()` function gets called, then `MyList` gives me incorrect information(saw it myself in the debugger).

I'm sorry if I did some wrong things, but I'm new to Xamarin.
I hope you can help me.

Comment: can you define "incorrect information"?

Comment: if you mean that checks are from then it is because you never save the state of the checkbox back to model

Comment: in my listview the checkbox state is wrong

Comment: you dont seem to understand how a listview is working, check xamarin tutorials: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/

Answer (score 0):

You're only reading the check box state, you're never saving it when it changes. Add this in your GetView:

```
            MyCheckBox.CheckedChange += (sender, e) =>
            {
                items[position].Done = e.IsChecked;
            };
```